# Register partically closed generic type with Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac, unit-of-work

I have `UnitofWork` class and it implement `IUnitOfWork`. I try to register that with Autofac:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<Repository<>,>))
    .As(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

Implementation is:

```
public class UnitOfWork<T, O> : IUnitOfWork
    where T : Repository<O>
    where O : BaseEntity
{
}

public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

Gives an error **"Type expected"**

but this one work on another project:

```
public class Repository<T> : GenericRepository<T> 
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    public Repository(IDbContext context) : base(context) { }   
}

public abstract class GenericRepository<T> 
    : IRepository<T>, IQueryable<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
}

builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Comment: "Gives an error "Type expected". You must be more explicit. You mean that the C# compiler give this error, right?

Comment: Sorry, project couldn't compile and gives an error "Type Expected" for UnitOfWork<T, O>

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You **cannot have partially opened classes** (e.g. with `UnitOfWork<Repository<>,>` you have specified `T` but not `O`) **inside a `typeof`**, try it with:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<,>))
    .As(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

The `where T : Repository<O>` generic constraint will take care of that the first argument should be an `Repository<>`

**But it won't work with `RegisterGeneric` because it requires a generic interface** so need to create a `IUnitOfWork<T,O>`…

But your model is very strange. Why does your `UnitOfWork` need a `Repository<>` type argument?

Instead of having it as a type argument you can get an `Repository<>` in your `UnitOfWork<E>` constructor:

```
public class UnitOfWork<E> : IUnitOfWork<E> where E : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly Repository<E> repository;

    public UnitOfWork(Repository<E> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    //.. other methods

}
```

Where  `IUnitOfWork<E>`

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<E> : IDisposable where E : BaseEntity
{
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

And the Autofac registration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).AsSelf();
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(UnitOfWork<>))
    .As(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>))
    .InstancePerDependency();
var container = builder.Build();

// sample usage
var u = container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork<MyEntity>>();
```

Comment: whats your suggestion for second repositories (third and more...)?

Comment: What do you mean on "second repositories (third and more...)"? You already have a `Repository<>` or you want to have custom derived repositories? If yes than you will need my first suggestion with the `IUnitOfWork<T,O>` where you specify the repository and also the entity...

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this answer more than once. Thanks!

Comment: Something is wrong with wprapper's registration in my container. It throws exception that the Wrapper has not been registered. 

But in my opinion I'm dooing it right: 
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(QueryBusWrapper<,>))
                   .As(typeof(IQueryBusWrapper<>))
                   .InstancePerDependency();