# Better way to express multiple generic implemenations

Tags: c#, autofac

Wasn't quite sure how to title this. I have the following code:

```
builder.Register(context =>
{
    var bus = context.Resolve<IBus>();
    return bus.CreatePublishRequestClient<IGenerateProjectReport, IGenerateReportResult>(MessagingTimeout);
}).As<IRequestClient<IGenerateProjectReport, IGenerateReportResult>>();

builder.Register(context =>
{
    var bus = context.Resolve<IBus>();
    return bus.CreatePublishRequestClient<IGenerateInstanceReport, IGenerateReportResult>(MessagingTimeout);
}).As<IRequestClient<IGenerateInstanceReport, IGenerateReportResult>>();

builder.Register(context =>
{
    var bus = context.Resolve<IBus>();
    return bus.CreatePublishRequestClient<IGenerateInternalReport, IGenerateReportResult>(MessagingTimeout);
}).As<IRequestClient<IGenerateInternalReport, IGenerateReportResult>>();
```

Is there a better way to express this? Seems a little redundant.

Edit:

I can't use the register generic capability to my knowledge since I have to use a factory method from another registered service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register Generic Type with Autofac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226536/register-generic-type-with-autofac)

Comment: @Igor Not quite. I use the pattern described in that post and my implementation doesn't quite fit since I'm calling a factory method from a resolved service.

Comment: Could you share interfaces contract ? how many registration do you have ? do you need to automatically register all your types based on a type constraint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom extension method to register your components :

I don't know how your types and type constraints are designed but something like this :

```
static class XXXRegistrationExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<PublishRequestClient<TReport>, SimpleActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle> RegisterXXX<TReport, TReportResult>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
        where TReport : IXXXReport
        where TReportResult : IXXXReportResult<TReport>
    {
        var registration = builder.Register(context =>
        {
            var bus = context.Resolve<IBus>();
            return bus.CreatePublishRequestClient<TReport, TReportResult>();
        }).As<IRequestClient<TReport, TReportResult>>();

        return registration;
    }
}
```

Then, you will be able to register your types as :

```
builder.RegisterXXX<IGenerateInternalReport, IGenerateReportResult>();
```

Comment: That makes sense, I was just wondering if Autofac had a built in mechanism to make this easier.