# Autofac Generic interface is not assignable to service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have like 20 registrations like these in an app:

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(FilterParser<>)).As(typeof(IFilterParser<>)).InstancePerDependency();
```

When I try to build my container I get an error like so:

> The type 'My.Namespace.FilterParser`1[TEntity]' is not assignable to service 'My.Namespace.IFilterParser`1'.'

Note the difference is the `[TEntity]` in the implementation and lack thereof in the interface.

My services do implement the interfaces:

```
public class FilterParser<TEntity> : IFilterParser<TEntity> where TEntity : new () 

public interface IFilterParser<TEntity> where TEntity : new ()
```

I also implemented this registration using .net core and it works just fine but in Autofac it just refuses to work.

I even tried `AsImplementedInterfaces` and I get the same error

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(FilterParser<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces()
                        .InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register Generic Type with Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226536/register-generic-type-with-autofac)

Comment: Sure, similar name but I don't have partially opened generics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `RegisterGeneric()` builder method:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FilterParser<>))
    .As(typeof(IFilterParser<>))
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

> When a matching service type is requested from the container, Autofac will map this to an equivalent closed version of the implementation type

Reference [Registration Concepts: Open Generic Components](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html?highlight=RegisterGeneric#open-generic-components)