# How to resolve generic type with dynamic parameter?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a generic class like

```
class EntityDao<T> where T: class
{
    void Update(T entity)
    {
       //Update entity to somewhere.
    }
}
```

while T might be any classes, like User, Company and etc.

I use Autofac to register EntityDao as Generic Type.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityDao<>));
var container = builder.Build();
```

In other places, I want to resove it dynamically.

```
string typeName = "User"; // might be "Company" or any other type name.

switch (typeName)
{
    case "User":
        container.Resolve<EntityDao<User>>().Update(entity);
        break;
    case "Company":
        container.Resolve<EntityDao<Company>>().Update(entity);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Here, typeName might have more than 50 values, and I thing there should be a generic way to avoid writing 50 cases.

Comment: Why not remove the constraint from the class and put it on the method? That way you wont need a switch on typename

Comment: Autofac doesn't offer this sort of thing out of the box. Whatever you write for it will end up being some sort of custom factory that uses reflection to build up some sort of lookup table that can match string to type/method.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot  have partially opened classes. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228731/15073910).
2. But you can [pass a parameter to a register](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html).